# openpyxl not opening my excel file : using online python compiler

Tags: python, openpyxl

I receive an error message stating that my Excel file doesn't exist whenever I try to load it with `openpyxl` using `pythonanywhere`.

Why might this be?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though it cant find the file that it is looking for. Something like this might help:

```
import os

path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/...") # Path to your file

for i in os.listdir(path):
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, i)):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(os.path.join(path, i))
```

Comment: Your answer worked as well ! ^_^ thanks a million Connor :)

Comment: @Silvia anytime

Answer (score 0):

I saved the excel file in "Files" section within pythonanywhere and commands

> > > import openpyxl
> > >
> > > wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')

worked ^_^